# What determines tablename in MongoDb Atlas

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm following a MERN tutorial, and I was wondering, what determines the table name that is created at Atlas.

For example, I this User model

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let User = require('../models/user.model');
//routes...
module.exports = router;
```

The table 'users' is created in Atlas when I send the very first POST request. What determines the naming of this table? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-model):

> When no collection argument is passed, Mongoose produces a collection name by passing the model name to the utils.toCollectionName method. This method pluralizes the name. If you don't like this behavior, either pass a collection name or set your schemas collection name option.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB database there are collections in which are documents with saved values. Collections are automatically created when you initialize them. So if you were to create an GET request at '/' route that would return certain collection, your result would be an empty array ([]). One of the simplest ways to initialize MongoDB database together with collections is with Monk like in the example below:

```
// REQUIRE MONK
const monk = require('monk');

// INITIALIZE DATABASE
const db = monk('localhost/faqs');

// INITIALIZE COLLECTION
const faqs = db.get('faqs');
    
    // THIS WOULD RETURN WHOLE COLLECTION
router.get('/',async (req,res,next) => {
   try {
      const items = await faqs.find({});
      res.json(items);
   } catch (err) {
     next(err);
        }
    })
```

You can install monk using npm:

```
npm i monk
```

Useful links:

MongoDB documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/

Monk documentation: https://automattic.github.io/monk/docs/GETTING_STARTED.html

My MERN stack Github project: https://github.com/gise19/MERN-FAQ